# When does the TransportEvent get fired in Java mail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get the Message-Id of the sent message by using listeners.
I am implementing
javax.mail.event.TransportListener with concrete methods given in code sample.

It listens to  javax.mail.event.TransportEvent which gets generated when void javax.mail.Transport.sendMessage(.....) is called.

To my surprise I get none of the method gets called when I actually send the mail..??? When does it actually get called ? Do I need to add any wait time after calling sendMessage(..)??

Doesn't it happen in real time ?

```
@Override
public void messageDelivered(TransportEvent e)
{
    try {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().getHeader("Message-Id")[0]);
    } catch (MessagingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void messageNotDelivered(TransportEvent e) 
{
    try {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().getHeader("Message-Id")[0]);
    } catch (MessagingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

@Override
public void messagePartiallyDelivered(TransportEvent e) 
{
    try {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().getHeader("Message-Id")[0]);
    } catch (MessagingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you register your listener with the Transport instance that's being used to send the message?  Remember that the static Transport.send() method creates its own Transport instance that you never see.

Comment: Done ! With a new transport instance and listener registration.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Can you please specify how you managed to register the TransportListener by providing sample code?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, can you please post your code here? caused I need to know how to capture those events too ... thanks in advanced :)

Comment: See the [JavaMail transport.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).

Comment: Hi, I know this is a very old post but I have a query, I'm getting `messageDelivered` event even when the email address is invalid. i.e it should have been `messageNotDelivered` isn't it ?

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Unless it is the immediate mail server you're talking to that detects the address is invalid, you won't get a transport event.  If your mail server accepts the message and sends it on to some other mail server, which then rejects it, it looks like success to JavaMail.